# Image::ExifTool 'Don't understand ImageInfo argument'

Tags: perl, exiftool

Like the title says, Image::ExifTool ImageInfo() does not understand my argument. Why?

```
if ( $form->submitted_and_valid ) {

my $photo = $c->model('DB::Photos')->create(
    {
        name     => $form->param('photo_name'),
        path     => $c->req->upload('photo')->fh,
        caption  => $form->param('caption'),
        uploaded => DateTime->now,
        mime => $mime->mimeTypeOf( $c->req->upload('photo')->basename ),
    }
);

$c->stash->{status_msg} = "Successfully uploaded!";
$c->stash->{photo}      = $photo;
$c->detach;
```

... Further on down, I grab the $photo object from the catalyst stash

```
my $data = $photo->path->open('r') or die;
my $exif = new Image::ExifTool;
my $info = $exif->ImageInfo($data) # <- this should be a ref to an open image file
```

Where is the issue here? This is a catalyst application, I am trying to get the exif_orientation of the file so I can rotate it if need be to display it appropriately on the webpage. But, I can not for the life of me get the exif information on the image file.

here is the path to the file. Yes, this file exist! I can display it on the webpage using this path.

```
/usr/local/docs/www.test.com/public/myapp/root/static/photos/52/52A1F1BC-0281-11E7-A32D-B12F1463937A
```

I have also checked using an external tool that the images i am using do indeed contain exif information.

Comment: What is `$photo`?

Comment: $photo is the the object returned from a call to the DB. It contains the path that of the file I want to open. $photo->path returns the directory location of the file that was uploaded by the user. I followed this guide quite closely http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2008/5

Comment: A database returns numbers or strings. `$photo` is an object. What class is it?

Comment: it is a catalyst Model `$c->model()->create()`

Comment: Okay, but I can't debug your code without knowing anything about the way the objects behave. Have you checked what's in `$data`? Try dumping it.

Comment: Dumper($data)`$VAR1 = bless( \*Symbol::GEN14, 'IO::File' );`

Comment: From the module's code, it looks like it won't accept an `IO::File` object. Try passing the path and letting it open the file itself. `my $info = $exif->ImageInfo($photo->path)` if the `path` method stringifies to the file path.

Comment: Ok, I tried the above advice. First I checked to make sure I was passing a string. `$photo->path` returns a Path::Class::File object. I changed the code to `my $info = $exif->ImageInfo($photo->path->stringify);` Dumped to verify a string. Still the same error. **Don't understand ImageInfo argument REF(0xXXXXXXXXX)**

Comment: Wait a minute, maybe this message isn't as relevant as I thought. Because when I dump `$info` it looks correct. Apparently that code is working.

Comment: Are you sure the message is coming from that line of your code? Yes, it's only a warning, but `REF(0xXXXXXXXX)` is a copy of the argument it doesn't understand, which isn't a simple string as you said.

Comment: Well you have helped me tremendously! I now have the information I need (even though I see my other problem now). As per the original question I posted above, if you want to post the answer I will surely give you credit. `my $info = $exif->ImageInfo($photo->path->stringify)` or `my $info = $exif->ImageInfo("$photo->path")` would work. Thank You

Comment: Okay I'll write it up tomorrow when I get back to a PC. I don't really feel the problem has been resolved properly, but I'm pleased to have helped.

Comment: Well you are correct about that. There is some trickery going on here and the documentation is sort of parse for my understanding. Quite simply I want to display a photo on the webpage in the correct orientation. It seems that when I open the file that is saved to disk I am not getting back all of the original METADATA that I need, Specifically the **Orientation**. Trying to get the **Orientation** from $c->req->upload() works using ImageInfo(). But, that seems to offset the file and now the file isn't a valid **jpeg** anymore.

Comment: I am having a hard time explaining exactly the issue, because I am not sure of what the appropriate manner of execution is here. Not getting all of the METADATA back from an open file saved to disk, that is there in the one being uploaded is confusing me